# Visual Studio 2017 15.8-up arrow repeat scrolls with page up?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I updated to VS 2017 15.8 last week, and I noticed right away that if I have a long file open, keyboard scrolling behaviour has changed.  Holding the down arrow still works the same way, but holding up will go to the top of the screen, but then page up the code (rather than scrolling smoothly).  I didn't see anything in the release notes about a change like this, I haven't changed any IDE options, and haven't found anything in the settings that would reference scrolling behaviour.  Has something changed behind the scenes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is fixed in VS 15.9.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this too - I've just updated to 15.8.2 and it has reverted back to the original behaviour.